# AWS - Is there an UI tool for setting/editing auto-scaling groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

Is there a tool that simplifies the auto-scaling group management? XML-based, UI-based, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am working on this myself and really the only two options I have found so far is the ec2 api tools - http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351 and the boto python library - https://github.com/boto/boto

Haven't seen anything ui based or xml based.

Also this tutorial helped me - http://www.caseylabs.com/how-to-setup-auto-scaling-on-amazon-ec2